# error [Dagger/DependencyCycle] found dependency cycle

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm using hilt and i tried to fix this error. but i can't fix this error. I want to use interceptor for refreshing my token when deprected. I shared my network module class and interceptor class. How can i request api service method in my interceptor class when using dependency injection library

Interceptor class:

```
    class AuthInterceptor @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) : Interceptor, Authenticator {

    private val preferenceProvider = PreferenceProvider()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        request = request.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        val token = preferenceProvider.getString(PREF_TOKEN) ?: return null
        ....        
        return null
    }
}
```

network module class:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHttpClient(authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .authenticator(authInterceptor)
        return builder.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitInstance(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory) : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE URL).client(okHttpClient).addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory).build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

my error:

> .ApiService is injected at
> AuthInterceptor(apiService)
> .AuthInterceptor is injected at
> .NetworkModule.provideHttpClient(authInterceptor)
> okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
> .NetworkModule.provideRetrofitInstance(okHttpClient, �)
> retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
> .NetworkModule.provideApiService(retrofit)
> .ApiService is injected at
> .AuthInterceptor(apiService)
> ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a cyclic dependency problem.
This authenticator is part of the Okhttp that is used in your retrofit service.

The way to get around this is to use a separate instance of retrofit which uses a
an okhttp without an authenticator.

You can use a named retrofit instance